# A partir da View como pegar a Model na Partial View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Na *View* principal, `Index.cshtml`, carrego uma *partial view* onde esta tem um *model*. Como fazer que a Index chame esse *model* para que eu possa serializar e mandar para uma *action* no *controller*?

Segue exemplo abaixo:

View Principal.cshtml

```
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>Glossário de Termos de Arquitetura
                    de Software</h1>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
}

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function atualizarDefinicao() {
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));  //<--- aqui: como pegar Model que está na parcialView? ou seja preciso pegar os campos que estão na partial view
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Index/DefinicaoArquitetura',
            data: JSON.stringify(model), //aqui envio para a action do controller
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#definicaoArquitetura').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(atualizarDefinicao, 30000);
    });

</script>

<p>
    Última atualização completa desta página:
        @DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
</p>

<h3>Definição:</h3>
<form id="myform">
<div id="definicaoArquitetura">

</div>
</fom>

<input id="btnProximaDefinicao"
    type="button"
    value="Próxima Definição"
    onclick="atualizarDefinicao();" />
```

Partial View DefinicaoArquitetura.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Sorteio.Models.MatrizSorteioModel>


<table width="100%" class="table" border="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <th class="fonte">
            &nbsp;
        </th>
        <th >
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.coluna_1)
        </th>
        <th >
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.coluna_2)
        </th>
        <th >
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.coluna_3)
        </th>
        <th >
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.coluna_4)
        </th>        
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td >
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coluna_1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coluna_2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coluna_3)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coluna_4)
            </td>                
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Classe HomeController

```
...
public ActionResult DefinicaoArquitetura(List<MatrizSorteioModel> listaMatriz)
        {
            ...

            return PartialView("Tabela", listaMatriz);
        }
...
```

Comment: o que este método `set(...)` está fazendo? tente fazer apenas `var dados = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` e de preferencia faça isto fora do método `atualizarDefinicao`, para que o objeto não precise ser re-instanciado a cada interação do método. E na sua `HomeController`, você tem um método `public PartialResult DefinicaoArquitetura(MyModel model)`?

Comment: Toby. Era um erro. Dei uma atualizada melhor para o seu melhor entendimento. O que eu preciso mesmo é uma forma de pegar os campos da partialView para serializar.

Comment: Não entendi nada. Qual o seu objetivo com isso?

Comment: Cigano, a minha dívida basicamante é como pegar o objeto Model que está na Partial View. Se esse objeto estiver na pagina atual consigo pegar. Veja o comentário no código.

Comment: @Leandro, dá uma olhada neste [exemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GuwLhq)

Answer (score 1):

Ainda não entendi o porquê disso, mas a maneira correta de enviar é transformando o conteúdo da *Partial* em campos de *form*. Pode ser por `<input type="hidden">`:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{        
    <tr>       
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coluna_1)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.coluna_1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coluna_2)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.coluna_2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coluna_3)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.coluna_3)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coluna_4)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.coluna_4)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Mas como estamos lidando com uma lista de elementos, além de passar tudo para *form*, você vai precisar usar o [pacote NuGet BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). Ficaria assim:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("listaMatriz"))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coluna_1)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.coluna_1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coluna_2)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.coluna_2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coluna_3)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.coluna_3)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coluna_4)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.coluna_4)
            </td>                
        </tr>
    }
}
```

[Há diversos exemplos de como usar o BeginCollectionItem aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+begincollectionitem).

Comment: agora entendi porque você não tava entendendo. Tinha um erro no meu código. No trecho de código estava ...  JSON.stringify(data) ... e corrigi para ... JSON.stringify(model) ...

Comment: @Leandro, o que ele não consegue entender é a sua necessidade de enviar o modelo através de uma requisição AJAX para preencher uma PartialView. Eu também não estou entendo o pq disto.

Comment: @Leandro A resposta atende ao que você precisa? Devo fazer algum complemento?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez agora não poderei ver isso. O que eu quero é: capturar os elementos do form da partial view, serializar  e passar para action via ajax.  Quando chegar em casa farei o teste. Qualquer coisa lhe aviso. Obrigado mesmo.